How to enginner support for this garage footing?
We have this wonky footing under our garage. There will eventually be stairs going alongside it and I'm curious how I should go about keeping that footer supported. New cement footer + rebar underneath or something different?


What will the stairs be made of?

@Huesmann concrete stairs. I talked to a couple of concrete guys and they mentioned making a new footer at the bottom of that empty space below the current footer then concrete + rebar up to the current footer.

This looks like a normal stepped foundation. The soil below the footing still supports the footing -- unless that soil falls out. The concrete side wall of your stair well could serve as a retaining wall to keep the soil in place. It might be necessary to attach the new concrete wall to the existing footing so it can't tilt inward, but I can't advise on that. Also a portion of the footing is now exposed to frost where it wasn't before. It might be advisable to place foam insulation board between the vertical soil face and the new concrete.

@GregHill Good suggestion. Currently I'm talking to a couple of licensed civil engineers to see what we can do here. It sounds like we'll end up doing very similarly to what you suggested with continuing the footer down.

I drew up all the plans for this and sent it to an engineering group. For $750 they drafted it up to code and I submitted it to the city.
They only thing they did different was 16" horizontal and 24" vertical rebar for the retaining wall (I had 18" each way)
